# How to get street view in angular-maps (agm-map)

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular5, angular-directive, google-street-view

I am trying to add a street view overlay on agm-map to be accessed on toggle of a custom button.

But, I am unable to access and modify the street view for this map element.

Can someone help point me in the right direction? I am trying to do something like the below example. It looks simple in javascript, but I am struggling to achieve the same in Angular 5

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewOverlays